# I cannot add geom_point on top of an existing geom_map, "differing number of rows"?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, gis

I am trying to make a map using ggplot2 and geom_map, but I am having trouble doing what should be an easy thing... adding a set of coordinates on top!

Here is my first bit of the code for the base map, based upon a shapefile I already have loaded in as `mapbasis`:

```
p1<-ggplot(mapbasis,aes(long,lat,map_id=id,fill=id))+
  geom_map(map=mapbasis)
```

[This works as expected:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBxvF.png)

Just to test the code I now create a data frame with just some coordinates:

```
test<-data.frame(pointid=c(1,2,3),lat=c(53, 51, 50),lon=c(-0.2, -0.1, -1.4))
```

I then try to add the points as follows:

```
p1+geom_point(aes(x=lon,y=lat),size=10,data=test)
```

I then, rather than having a map with three points on it, end up with the error message:

```
Error in data.frame ... arguments imply differing number of rows: 3,0
```

What is going on? I clearly have both longitude and latitude coordinates. I have also tried plotting just the `test` object and it works fine.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong?

Comment: Maybe inherite.aes = false could fix this?

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. So perhaps it was getting confused between the original aesthetic and the new one given in the geom_point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by @TinglTanglBob

Use inherit.aes=FALSE to prevent confusion between the original aesthetic defined in the geom_map, and the new aes given in the geom_point,